# How to open a tkinter window when a key is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
#console
if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
    console=Tk()
    console.geometry("500x425")
    console.title("Devoloper Console")
    console.resizable(True,True)
    console.configure(bg='gray95')
```

Basically, I'm trying to use the keyboard module to detect when I press <kbd>C</kbd> on my keyboard, and then open a Tkinter window when I press <kbd>C</kbd>.

The code above doesn't work (obviously) and I don't know why. However, I do know that the problem is that it isn't detecting the keypress and not a problem with the window.

Comment: You need a loop to constantly check if key has been pressed.

Comment: So you want the UI to open when you press C or do you want a sub-window to open when you press c?

Answer (score 1):

Module `keyboard` has a function called `wait`. It waits for a key to be pressed. You have to use that. Also use `mainloop` for the tkinter window to make it run corectly.

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

keyboard.wait("c")   #< It'll wait for c to be pressed

console = tk.Tk()
console.geometry("500x425")
console.title("Devoloper Console")
console.resizable(True,True)
console.configure(bg='gray95')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a continuing loop to check when `c` is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

x = True

while x:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
        x = False
        console=Tk()
        console.geometry("500x425")
        console.title("Devoloper Console")
        console.resizable(True,True)
        console.configure(bg='gray95')
        console.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, The window wont open when the key is pressed

Comment: Works exactly as expected on my end. When I press `c` the root tkinter window opens with all the defined configs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

while (not keyboard.is_pressed("c")):
       pass

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<c>", lambda e: tk.Toplevel())
root.mainloop()
```

Does this do what you wanted?